# std::function with function as default parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have this method header:

```
void Find(const _T & v, int max, const function<bool(const _E &)> & filter)
```

I'm using `std::function` because I need to accept function pointer, functor or lambda expression. I would like the filter to be optional, and default to function that always return true (nothing is filtered out) as default parameter. I've tried something like this:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename E>
bool alwaystrue(const E & e){ return true; }

template <typename T, typename E>
void Find(const T & v, int max,
          const std::function<bool(const E &)> & filter = alwaystrue);

int main()
{
    Find<int, int>(1, 2);
}
```

But this doesn't compile:

```
50016981.cpp: In function ‘void Find(const T&, int, const std::function<bool(const E&)>&) [with T = int; E = int]’:
50016981.cpp:11:24: error: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘alwaystrue’ based on conversion to type ‘const std::function<bool(const int&)>&’
     Find<int, int>(1, 2);
                        ^
```

I've also tried having the function inside my class but got a similar error.

Is there a problem combining with `std::function` with templates? And if so, could you suggest how to do what I want? I want to avoid overloading the `Find()` function (if possible) so I don't have duplicate code.

Comment: How about using a lambda for the default argument? Or overloading?

Comment: On an unrelated note, please read [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) Symbols like your `_E` or `_T` are reserved in all scopes.

Comment: You have not specified the template arguments when using `alwaystrue` in the `Find` declaration.

Comment: What exactly the error is? What if you specialize your `alwaystrue` parameter: `void Find(const _T & v, int max, const function<bool(const _E &)> & filter = alwaystrue<_E>)` ?

Comment: @keith That was the problem, thank you.

Comment: @Alexey It works fine, when I specify the template argument, thank you.

Comment: BTW, identifiers beginning with underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved *for any purpose* in C++ (which means they may be macros).  Just lose those underscores and you'll be much safer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indicate which instantiation of `alwaystrue` you want to use as your default, i.e. `alwaystrue<E>`:

```
template <typename T, typename E>
void Find(const T& v, int max,
          const std::function<bool(const E&)>& filter = alwaystrue<E>);
```